# J2EE environment- Multithreading - Fetching data from different services in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, jakarta-ee, design-patterns

Is there any better alternative (design/performance/memory optimization) to what I have used below:

Problem statement: In J2EE environment, when a request comes my controller needs to fetch data from three different services (ex. 1st get weather data, 2nd gets traffic density, and the last one gets current no of aliens visited us). And if one service takes like 5 seconds (in best case) to fetch, then in synchronous manner they will take at least 15 Sec. But controller should not take more than 6-7 seconds. So end up calling in  different threads. But there might be cases when a service takes more than 10 seconds (may be a worst case scenario).

> 1. So I thought of creating a thread wait, notify using an observable pattern with a small state maintaining. It was working, but not happy
>      with the design.
> 2. Then I found Java 'ForkJoinPool'. For each request controller creates a new '`ForkJoinPool`' instance - now not creating it on each request. Created a custom
>      class (say `ForkService`) extending `RecursiveAction` which has a
>      `List<RecursiveAction>`. And ForkService's compute method has

```
@Override
    protected void compute() {
        for (RecursiveAction recursiveAction : actions) {
            recursiveAction.fork(); // async calling of all other service's compute method which actually fetches the data from the relevant service.
        }

        mPool.shutdown();
    }
```

Presently using this and it performs well. Want to know is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You're using Data Parallelism when you should be using Task Parallelism. There isn't a Task Parallel framework within core Java so Jean Logeart has a good solution. As @Floegipoky points out, creating/destroying the framework each time is awful. If you can use an outside product then I can steer you in that direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple and elegant way is to use a fixed thread pool and Guava's [`ListenableFuture`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html) on which you can call [`Futures.successfulAsList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#successfulAsList(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture...)):

```
private MyResult getResult(MyRequest request) {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    ListeningExecutorService les = MoreExecutorslisteningDecorator(es);

    ListenableFuture<?> lf1 = les.submit(getCallableForService1(request));
    ListenableFuture<?> lf2 = les.submit(getCallableForService2(request));
    ListenableFuture<?> lf3 = les.submit(getCallableForService3(request));
    ListenableFuture<List<?>> lfs = Futures.successfulAsList(lf1, lf2, lf3);

    // wait 7 sec for results
    List<?> res = lfs.get(7, TimeUnit.SEONDS);

    return extractRes(res);
}
```

You should of course handle the correct types for the `Callable`s.

Comment: In Java-EE environment, you should use ManagedExecutorService instead of using Java SE ExecutorService. Use @Resource to inject the instance of ManagedExecutorService.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not as familiar with the [Fork/Join framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html), but I can tell you right off the bat that creating a new threadpool for each request defeats half the purpose of a threadpool.  Threads are expensive to create and destroy, threadpools are used so that you can reuse threads.

Looking at the documentation, it seems like Fork/Join is intended for problems that are recursive in nature and require intensive processing.  Your problem doesn't seem to meet either of these criteria.

You'd probably be better off using a regular [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) that's shared by all of your requests.  The [invokeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) method will probably be especially helpful; You can submit all 3 requests at once, receive a `List<Future<T>>`, and even provide a timeout if you wish.

To get the results, you can simply loop over the `List<Future<Thing>> things`:

```
Thing[] results = new Thing[3];
for (int i = 0; i < things.size(); ++i) {
    results[i] = things.get(i).get();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Floegipoky. Now its a single instance.

Comment: Problem is how do I stop my main event loop / thread on which request is received! I don't want to check every second to see whether all services has responded. That's the reason in first solution I tried to use the observer pattern in which observable's inform that whether they succeed or failed.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but thought of writing what can be other options:
1. Usage of callbacks. Where as and when a thread completes the works it responds back via the callback.
2. Notifications: Each thread sends a notification on work completion.
3. Use of `RecursiveAction` as mentioned in the question.
4. Answer accepted as the final answer where it uses Guava library's `ListenableFuture`.